# fastapi Error: 'url_for' is undefined in jinja2 template

Tags: python, jinja2, fastapi

I was trying to run a simple app with `fastapi` and I have used `jinja2` for templating. I wanted to style my template with css. I have put the file into `static/styles.css`. And I have used `url_for` to use this file, whenever I run the app with `hypercorn main:app`. I am getting this error:

```
Error: 'url_for' is undefined
```

here is my app

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from send_mail import SendEmail

app = FastAPI()

app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")

@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    SendEmail(subject="Test", template_name="child")
    return 'succeed'
```

and here is my jinja template

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>   
    <title>Hello World</title>  
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', path='/styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">{% block content %}{% endblock %}</div>     
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the code of `sendEmail`:

```py
import os
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Mail
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Email
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Content
from jinja2 import FileSystemLoader, Environment, select_autoescape

...

def SendEmail(to_email, subject, template_name):
    try:
        # render jinja template
        templateLoader = FileSystemLoader(searchpath="templates")
        templateEnv = Environment(
            loader=templateLoader,
            autoescape=select_autoescape(['html', 'xml'])
        )
        html_template = templateEnv.get_template(template_name + ".html")
        html_to_send = html_template.render()
        html_content = Content("text/html", html_to_send)

        # copose the Mail
        message = Mail(
            ...
            html_content=html_content
        )

        sg = SendGridAPIClient(os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))
        response = sg.send(message)


    except Exception as e:
        print("Error: {0}".format(e))
```

Comment: What's inside `send_mail` and `SendEmail`? How are you asking for the templates to be rendered? FastAPI assumes you use the `Jinja2Templates` module if you want those functions to be available (they're not Jinja2 specific, they're provided by the framework around Jinja2). https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/templates/#using-jinja2templates

Comment: I will update the question, send_mail is a script containing SendEmail function I will add it is content

Comment: The `url_for` method is a method on the `Request` object, so if you're going to either use the preconfigured context through the templating support as linked above, or include `request: Request` to your view method and pass it along to the SendEmail function. `request.url_for(...)`

Comment: With the use of this ```   templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")
        html_content = templates.TemplateResponse("child.html", {"request": request})``` I am getting this error: `Error: '_TemplateResponse' object has no attribute 'mime_type'`.  Could not I stick with the first code instead and twick it to fix the issue? or if I should use the second approach could you share an example of code to clear up the confusion I am getting